Is there a shorter/more pythonic way of writing the 2nd line of this python code?
def triangle(side1, side2, side3):
    if side1 >= side2 + side3 or side2 >= side3 +side1 or side3 >= side1 + side2:
        return 'Not a triangle'
    elif side1 == side2 == side3:
        return 'Equilateral'
    elif side1 != side2 != side3:
        return 'Scalene'
    return 'Isosceles'

The code works fine, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to write line 2 of the code which goes
'if any one side of the triangle is greater than or equal to the sum of the other 2 sides':

If you sort the list of sides, you can improve not only the first test (as in the answer posted by user24731489) but also the equilateral test (one comparision instead of 2) and the isosceles test (two comparisions instead of 3).

Your code does not work fine. Due to how comparisons work in Python, triangle(2,3,2) will output "Scalene" even though it is Isosceles, because 2 != 3 and 3 != 2.

@VPfB But the sorting process itself will introduce more comparisons than you can save later on.

Note: Pythonic and shorter are not always compatible, nor fast (or efficient). Choose one.

If you adhere to the Zen of Python you will leave your second line alone. It's clear what you're doing and is very efficient

After testing the triangle inequality theorem (your second line) you could (not should) create a set from the 3 input parameters. If the set length is 1 then it's equilateral. If 2 it's isosceles otherwise (3) scalene

@matszwecja I think it depends on input, which comparison will succeed first. Without sorting: 1 to 8 comparisons (and max 3 sums), with sorting: 4 to 7 comparisons (and 1 sum). Counting the sort of 3 values as 3 comparisons. No free lunch, but maybe shorter code.

How about this -
def triangle(side1, side2, side3):
    sides = [side1, side2, side3]
    if max(sides) >= sum(sides) - max(sides):
        return 'Not a triangle'
    elif side1 == side2 == side3:
        return 'Equilateral'
    elif side1 != side2 and side2 != side3 and side1 != side3:
        return 'Scalene'
    return 'Isosceles'


The elifs could be shortened with len(set(sides)) and comparing to 2 or 3 meaning 2 sides are equal or none are equal, or 2 different sides and 3 different sides, however you prefer.

Although this may be considered more Pythonic by some, it's certainly way less efficient than the original code

Instead of evaluating max(sides) twice in max(sides) >= sum(sides) - max(sides) you can write the expression as 2 * max(sides) >= sum(sides).

To optimize, I would test equilateral and only after that check if it is not a triangle (and some people prefers if instead of elif after a return but it doesn't matter much. Also some test like: eq = (side1 == side2) + (side1 == side3) + (side2 == side3), and test 0, 1, or 3 may be more efficient.

There are shorter mathematical expressions for the same thing (eg 2*max-sum>=0).
However I think these would make the intention less clear, and require comments to explain where the logic comes from.
Your current code is good as it is clear what you're doing.
